# MySQL 'select WHERE like x OR y' multiple results for one row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, case, union

Alright, I tried to word the title as well as possible.  Here's what I'm looking for...let's say I've got a row with an ID of 3 in a table called 'table' with a 'col1' value of "apple,potato,carrot,squash" that I want to search.

I want to be able to do a search something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%potato%' OR col1 LIKE '%apple%';
```

...and I want it to result in two separate results for the row with the ID of 3.

I could parse out the results with PHP obviously, but it seems a lot more efficient to just get the results exactly as I want them directly from MySQL.  Is there a way to do this?

(Note that this is not a homework assignment or anything, I'm just trying to be as generic as possible for the sake of the example)

Comment: Why would it return two results?

Comment: Let's say col1 has "apple potato carrot", are you wanting: 3|potato, 3|apple?

Comment: @hjpotter92 Because potato and apple are both found in the result and it would split each match into a separate result.

Comment: @aust Sure, something like that would work I suppose.

Comment: Do you just want a count for each, or do you really need a separate record for each match?

Comment: Well actually, a count will definitely work.  If that query would give a result of 2 for that row because there were two matches, that would be perfect...I just assumed that was a bit much to ask of the DB and that my original question was the closest I'd get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nullifying the use of indexes with the `LIKE '%substring%'` query. Using `UNION ALL` with multiple queries would work, and it's simple. However, one drawback to that method is that MySQL will have to scan all the rows in the database for each subquery.

So, for a query like the following, assuming 1000 records:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%potato%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%apple%'
```

MySQL will have to scan through 2000 records (1000 * 2). Then, you have to process the results, when really, you just want a count. For three search types, it's 3000, etc. It doesn't scale well.

Instead, both for performance, and for simplicity (in processing the results), you can have MySQL do the work all at once with the `CASE` and `SUM` statements:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.col1 LIKE '%potato%'  THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS numPotatoes,
       SUM(CASE 
             WHEN t.col1 LIKE '%apple%' THEN 1
             ELSE 0
           END) AS numApples
  FROM table t
```

This allows MySQL to scan through all the records just once and return your actual counts.

Comment: Was the requirement to count appearances? I understood it was to list the rows.

Comment: @FrankPl, please read the latest comments for the question. It does help to ask for what you want.

Comment: Ok, now I see the question was kind of changed.

Comment: Beautiful.  Thank you so much.  Yeah, I should have just asked for what I wanted instead of trying to get there in steps.

Answer (score 3):

If you really need it to return 2 results then you could do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%potato%' 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col1 LIKE '%apple%'
```

Comment: And for best practice, always use a column list.

Comment: Not to mention the good practise of mentioning the columns too.

Comment: Without `UNION ALL`, I don't see how this will return 2 rows for a match.

Comment: *@ypercube*, agreed and fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to formulate the query in a "general" way, making it easier to add in new comparisons:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t join
     (select '%potato%' as str union all
      select '%apple%'
     ) comp
     on t.col1 like comp.str;
```

That said, I would suggest the following variant:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM table t join
     (select 'potato' as item union all
      select 'apple'
     ) comp
     on find_in_set(comp.item, t.col1) > 0
```

Comment: Okay, thanks...haha I've got a bit of research to do, I've never used union, comp, as, or field_in_set

Comment: Would there be a way to organize the results with the id as the key via PHP's PDO?  As in, if the id is 3, this would end in a variable something like this: $result[3][0] and $result[3][1]